# Multiple File Input in LARAVEL 7

Tags: php, laravel, forms, input

I am trying to make an upload modal where the user can upload a project containing a Title, Cover image and **gallery of images**.

For that I thought about using the input element with the property 'multiple'.

```html
        <div class="addSection">
            <form action="{{ route('architecture', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()] ) }}" method="POST" class="sectionUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                <label for="projectTitle">Project title: </label>
                <input type="text" id="sectionTitle" name="projectTitle" placeholder=" (example: 1978-Reel-Boom)">
                <label for="projectCover">Cover image: </label>
                <input type="file" id="sectionCover" name="projectCover">
                <br>
                <label for="projectGallery">Gallery images: </label>
                <input type="file" id="sectionGallery" name="projectGallery" multiple>
                <button type="submit" id="uploadNewSection" name="uploadNewProject" value="Upload">Upload new project</button>
            </form>
```

When doing a dd() on the projectGallery in my controller, I only recieve the latest selected image.

```php
    public function addProject(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'projectTitle' => 'required',
            'projectCover' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048',
            'projectGallery' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
        ]);

        dd($request->projectGallery);
    }
```

Any Idea what I might be doing wrong? I just need an array of the selected images to upload the names into my DB table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add name as `projectGallery[]`

```
 <input type="file" id="sectionGallery" name="projectGallery[]" multiple>
```

Also update validation

```
'projectGallery.*' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
```